# Deploying site pages in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, deployment

I have around 9 web parts and 3 pages to be deployed. Each page will be having 3 webparts.
From a deploymnet perspective, i think i have the following two options:

1. Deploy the pages using a feature. The pages will have webparts present.
2. Create a custom site definition  with a document library and have the three pages as part of the document library.

Can you please let me know which one of the options is better or is there any better solution?.

Please note that the solution needs to work on WSS 3.0 as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would code the whole thing as a feature. You can staple it to the site definition for the site type you want it activated on.

If ever you need to migrate to the next version of SharePoint or another server it is easier to not have any custom site definitions. Also, the features leaves the site in a normal out-of-the box state; if you ever remove the feature nothing breaks.

Also, unlike the site definition it will also allow you to run it on sites that where created in the past.

Answer (score -2):

First you need to deploy the webparts using WSP. Once it populated in webpart gallery you can copy the pages from page library and can paste in production.

Comment: Copy & paste is not a particularly good idea when you can just include pages in the solution, and probably wouldn't work in this case anyway.

Comment: True. Copy & paste should never be done when you are moving stuff to the production. It should be avoided locally too.